# jailkit chroot terminates ssh login

Tags: linux, jail, chroot

I've done my very best to follow [these instructions](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_chroot_shell.html) to create a chroot shell. But the connection get's terminated every time I try to login via ssh for my new chrooted user.

I start my ssh terminal, login via chrooteduser and then as soon as I'm logged in it quits...

I'm new to a lot of the linux world so I'm just not sure what might be causing this problem.

**EDIT**

Here's a log of the attempted login from chrooteduser:

```
Apr  1 06:55:13 li244-40 sshd[2453]: Accepted password for testroo from 114.77.115.211 port 57658 ssh2
Apr  1 06:55:13 li244-40 sshd[2453]: pam_env(sshd:setcred): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Apr  1 06:55:13 li244-40 sshd[2453]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user testroo by (uid=0)
Apr  1 06:55:13 li244-40 sshd[2466]: pam_env(sshd:setcred): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Apr  1 06:55:14 li244-40 jk_chrootsh[2468]: path /home/newroo/./home/testroo is not owned by group 5004
Apr  1 06:55:14 li244-40 jk_chrootsh[2468]: abort, path /home/newroo/./home/testroo does not have group owner 5004, set option 'relax_home_group' to relax this check
Apr  1 06:55:14 li244-40 sshd[2453]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user testroo
Apr  1 06:55:14 li244-40 sshd[2453]: pam_env(sshd:setcred): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, Problem sovled. Don't you just love solving your own problems!

The problem was that the chrooted home directory didn't have the right permissions. As I discovered by looking at the log.